# Full page template function

Tags: functions, templates

I would like to be able to create page templates that all look almost the same, and have a template I would like to use.

I would only like to change certain fields for the page, for example:

header title
post category
posts category
social media follow button link, a color

I have managed to create functions to output sets of posts (thanks to people on this forum as well as WordPress's), but now I would like that function to be the whole page.

I would like to put on page "pine-trees.php":

Then I could add any css changes internally.

and output the template using Pine Trees data. Then I would do it with Grizzly Bears, etc.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. You have a lot of very vague "wishes" here, not really a question.